# In C#, best way to check if stringbuilder contains a substring

Tags: c#, string, contains, stringbuilder

I have an existing `StringBuilder` object, the code appends some values and a delimiter to it.

I want to modify the code to add the logic that before appending the text, it will check if it already exists in the `StringBuilder`. If it does not, only then will it append the text, otherwise it is ignored.

What is the best way to do so? Do I need to change the object to `string` type? I need the best approach that will not hamper performance.

```
public static string BuildUniqueIDList(context RequestContext)
{
    string rtnvalue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        StringBuilder strUIDList = new StringBuilder(100);
        for (int iCntr = 0; iCntr < RequestContext.accounts.Length; iCntr++)
        {
            if (iCntr > 0)
            {
                strUIDList.Append(",");
            }

            // need to do somthing like:
            // strUIDList.Contains(RequestContext.accounts[iCntr].uniqueid) then continue
            // otherwise append
            strUIDList.Append(RequestContext.accounts[iCntr].uniqueid);
        }
        rtnvalue = strUIDList.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return rtnvalue;
}
```

I am not sure if having something like this will be efficient:

```
if (!strUIDList.ToString().Contains(RequestContext.accounts[iCntr].uniqueid.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I would use:

```
return string.Join(",", RequestContext.accounts
                                      .Select(x => x.uniqueid)
                                      .Distinct());
```

No need to loop explicitly, manually use a `StringBuilder` etc... just express it all declaratively :)

(You'd need to call `ToArray()` at the end if you're not using .NET 4, which would obviously reduce the efficiency somewhat... but I doubt it'll become a bottleneck for your app.)

EDIT: Okay, for a non-LINQ solution... if the size is *reasonably* small I'd just for for:

```
// First create a list of unique elements
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
foreach (var account in RequestContext.accounts)
{
    string id = account.uniqueid;
    if (ids.Contains(id))
    {
        ids.Add(id);
    }
}

// Then convert it into a string.
// You could use string.Join(",", ids.ToArray()) here instead.
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string id in ids)
{
    builder.Append(id);
    builder.Append(",");
}
if (builder.Length > 0)
{
    builder.Length--; // Chop off the trailing comma
}
return builder.ToString();
```

If you could have a *large* collection of strings, you might use `Dictionary<string, string>` as a sort of fake `HashSet<string>`.

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned it, can I do this without LINQ? In .net 2.0?

Comment: @user465876: You can, but personally I'd get hold of LINQBridge instead... LINQ is *so* useful, it's worth getting hold of the backport.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the tip. Soon we will be moving to 3.5 and then I will defiently use LINQ to the max. But for the timebeing, I need to stick to non-LINQ solution :( If you don't mind, can you tell me how to do this in 2.0 without LINQ/LINQBridge.

Comment: @user465876: Okay, I've added an alternative for .NET 2.

Comment: thanks Jon. It is really helpful. I will keep in mind about LINQ.