# StringBuilder Add parenthesis

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am trying to add parenthesis inside a stringbuilder object, but not sure how to do that as stringbuilder does not have contains method like String.

In my caseI create a stringbuilder object based on business rules and when certain column is present in stringbuilder I have to go to the start of that word add parenthesis there and then append some chars to it.

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
result.AppendFormat(" L.AddressSearchNumber = 100 AND L.AddressStreet <> 'Main' ");
if(flag)
{
  result.AppendFormat(" OR L.AddressStreet IS NULL");
}
```

but I want to add parenthesis like -

```
L.AddressSearchNumber = 100 AND (L.AddressStreet <> 'Main' OR L.AddressStreet IS NULL)
```

I am not sure how can I get index of L.AddressStreet add parenthesis before it in stringbuilder.

Comment: look at this example for starters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119423/in-c-best-way-to-check-if-stringbuilder-contains-a-substring

Comment: Split your IF differently. Start with the appendFormat of the piece that is constant. Then in the if append only the <> 'Main' and in the else add the Is Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the code express the underlying logic:

```
result.AppendFormat(" L.AddressSearchNumber = 100"); 
if(flag)
{
  result.AppendFormat(" AND (L.AddressStreet <> 'Main'  OR L.AddressStreet IS NULL )");
}
else
{
  result.AppendFormat(" AND L.AddressStreet <> 'Main' ");
}
```

You can refactor the duplicate `L.AddressStreet <> 'Main'` out but that's not urgent.

Comment: looks pretty simple and straight forward not sure why the OP made this such an issue

Comment: Answer is correct formally. But if this is an SQL query, will `(L.AddressStreet <> 'Main'  OR L.AddressStreet IS NULL )` not be equivalent to `L.AddressStreet <> 'Main'`? If a column is `NULL`, then in particular it is distinct from `'Main'`, I guess.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Yes, I just Copy/Pasted from the question. But the question is about filling the SB, the OP may have mixed up the sample code. Or he has an SQL bug.

Comment: Hi guys, this worked pretty well. I had thought about it. but I was thinking about manipulating stringbuilder to make this change. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: You could still clear up the `<> Main OR is null` confusion in the question. For future visitors.